# Configuring tkinter for python3.4.3 Problem

Tags: python, raspberrypi, tkinter

I'm decently new to using a Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to set up a simple GUI application to launch from my Pi. I'm using a Raspberry Pi3, with Python 3.4.3 installed.

When I type `python`:

```
~$ python
Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 21 2015, 00:53:08)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When I try to import tkinter:

```
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
        import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
>>>
```

So, I can see that the error is coming from miniconda3. The only reason I had it installed was to use PyQt5, but I was getting a similar error when I tried to use that, so I switched over to Tkinter because there were more examples of using it with a pi online.

I have run the following commands to try to install Tkinter:

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
sudo apt-get install python-tk
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

How can I fix this? I have read in some places to `make` python again, but no one says how to do that.

Thanks guys!

Comment: It seems you are launching miniconda python not python with comes with raspberry-pi distribution. Could post the output of `which python` and try if tk works when lauching python using `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @user.dz This was exactly the issue! Now there is no import issue when I try to import. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Install the Tkinter package for writing Tk applications with Python 3.x. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-tk # for Python 2.x install python-tk
```

Then run `/usr/bin/python3` to start the default Python 3 that comes with Ubuntu and `import tkinter` will work.

Answer (score 1):

- It seems that you are launching mini-conda python not python that comes with raspberry-pi distribution. You could check the output of:

  ```
  which python
  ```

  Expected output: `/usr/local/bin/python` or mini-conda custom installation path (if it was added before.)
- Test also if Tk works when launching python using absolute path:

  ```
  /usr/bin/python
  ```
- To complete my answer, if you like to use miniconda python, use its own installation method:

  ```
  conda install packagename
  ```

  Reference: [Miniconda homepage](https://conda.io/miniconda.html), :) I'm not aware of the exact package name of tkinter.