# I don't have Python 3.6.1 IDLE and tkinter won't work

Tags: python

I installed python 3.6.1. But then realized I don't have IDLE and can only access python via terminal by typing `python`. And the python version in the terminal is 2.7.12 not 3.6.1. I know Ubuntu comes with Python 2.7.12. But how come I can't use 3.6.1?

Comment: use `python3` to invoke it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring tkinter for python3.4.3 Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896825/configuring-tkinter-for-python3-4-3-problem) and [How shall I install and invoke IDLE for Python3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961991/how-shall-i-install-and-invoke-idle-for-python3)

Answer (score 2):

To use Python3, type `python3` in your terminal.

To use tkinter, you need to install it by typing

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```