# How shall I install and invoke IDLE for Python3?

Tags: python3, idle-python

In Ubuntu, I tried to invoke IDLE

```
$ python3 -m idlelib
** IDLE can't import Tkinter.
Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **
```

How shall I solve the problem?

I attempted to install `idle` by `sudo apt-get install idle`, but after that, running `idle` will invoke a shell for Python2.7 not for Python3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IDLE 3 is an Integrated Development Environment for Python 3.x. IDLE 3 is written using Tkinter and therefore quite platform-independent. To install idle3 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install idle3
```

Then the command `python3 -m idlelib` will work open IDLE 3 successfully.

To install IDLE for both Python 2.x and Python 3.x open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install idle idle3
```